# ¿Cómo puedo unir todos los diccionarios?

Tags: python

tengo esta función que cuenta las vocales de 100 tweets, pero necesito que toda la suma quede en un solo diccionario

```
  for n in range(100):
    a = my_tweets[n].count('a')
    e = my_tweets[n].count('e')
    i = my_tweets[n].count('i')
    o = my_tweets[n].count('o')
    u = my_tweets[n].count('u')
    vocales= {'a': a, 'e': e, 'i': i, 'o': o, 'u': u}
    print(vocales)
```

Comment: Puedes extender tu pregunta? No entiendo que quieres realmente

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás iterando sobre una lista pero no estás acumulando los valores:

```
a = e = i = o = u = 0
for n in range(100):
    a = a + my_tweets[n].count('a')
    e = e + my_tweets[n].count('e')
    i = i + my_tweets[n].count('i')
    o = o + my_tweets[n].count('o')
    u = u + my_tweets[n].count('u')

vocales= {'a': a, 'e': e, 'i': i, 'o': o, 'u': u}
print(vocales)
```

Primero que nada creamos unas variable temporales y las inicializamos en 0 con `a = e = i = o = u = 0`, luego dentro del ciclo las vamos sumando, por ej: `a = a + my_tweets[n].count('a')`. Finalmente fuera del ciclo, construyes el diccionario, ahora sí con los totales.

Answer (score 0):

Primero creas un diccionario con llave vocal y valor cuantas veces aparece dicha vocal. Inicialmente en cero.

```
vocales = dict(a=0, e=0, i=0, o=0, u=0)
```

Luego un `for` para recorrer los tweets, otro para recorrer las vocales:

```
for n in range(len(my_tweets)):
    for letra in "aeiou":
        vocales[letra] += my_tweets[n].count(letra)
```

#### Demo

```
my_tweets = ["uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco"]

vocales = dict(a=0, e=0, i=0, o=0, u=0)
for n in range(len(my_tweets)):
    for letra in "aeiou":
        vocales[letra] += my_tweets[n].count(letra)
print(vocales)
```

produce:

```
{'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'i': 1, 'o': 4, 'u': 2}

Process finished with exit code 0
```